# select data using pandas only if the subject mean is higher than X

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with a column subject and rows subj1 and subj2 subjX

I want to select only those Subjects in which the mean of another column (Conf) is higher than 5

if I use: 
byP=id_data.groupby('Subject')

byP.Confidence.mean()<5

then I can get the Subjects which meet that criteria
Subject
Sbj_08_5161     True
Sbj_09_2982     True
Sbj_12_3413    False
Sbj_13_5102    False
...
...
...
Sbj_14_7141     True

but then how can I select from the original id_data frame only those Subjects that are True?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`:

```
df=id_data[id_data.groupby('Subject').Confidence.transform('mean')<5]
```

Comment: df=id_data[id_data.groupby('Subject').Confidence.mean() <5 ]
also works